# How to begin SAPI speaking a few characters back?

Tags: char, sapi

I have a small problem in my code. I have programmed my program to find word inside a .`txt` file and now I want to know how to make SAPI speaking from 5000 characters from the place the word is found inside the `.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the position of the word in the file it shouldn't be a challenge to read the next 5000 characters into a buffer that can then be fed to the speech engine. It's possible that a hard 5000 character cutoff will leave a word broken at the end so you may want to seek ahead past that point to the next blank space or whatever to make the end smoother.

Without knowing specifics like language and platform and which SAPI you are using it is impossible to give more detailed advice.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answering! Secondly I'm working on C# environment, and I'm in mid-knowledge of language. Can you give me an example on how to store the PREVIOUS 5000 and the NEXT 5000 chars between the word on a buffer,based on SAPI on Windows 8.1. Thanks in advice.!

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any c# experience. This may help you https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Speech-synthesis-sample-6e07b218